# Restoring site on localhost: keep redirecting back to old URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup, localhost

I've backup my Joomla 3.3.1 website with Akeeba backup. I've installed this backup on a localhost (Xampp) with Akeeba kickstart.

I can access the backend with this address: `http://localhost/joomla/administrator` and everything is correctly installed.

But when I try to connect to the front-end, on this address `http://localhost/joomla/`,  I get a 404 error:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
```

Before getting this error I was redirected to the original site URL, so I commented out those lines in my .htacess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any idea what I am suppose to do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have acces to the backend, try disabling the SEF configurations.

EDIT: then you have an issue with rewrite rules, check with an original .htaccess (cf joomla installation package) after that you can reenable SEF as it should work xampp.